# How to count this measure?

Tags: guitar, sheet-music, rhythm

I am learning a piece and am new to sheet music. I am trying to count the beats, and need to some help in counting.
It's in the time signature 4/4.
For the second bar, how should I count it out?

My interpretation:

```
 (0 3) 1 & beat 
 0--    ?
 2---   ?
 (3 0) 1  & beat
```

[image: guitar tab in 4/4 time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(0 3)   1 &
(0 2)   2 & 3 &
(3 0)   4 &
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is plucked guitar strings without any active muting.
Hence the notes will continue to ring out, but won't really be "held" in the same sense the other instrument might do.

I'm not sure why it's been written the way shown (as two seperate voice), but if you rewrite it as a *single* voice (removing the unnecessary tied notes etc.), it is much easier to see the rhythm:

[image: excerpt rewritten as a single voice, with beats show below]

(**PS** I don't understand your notation at all.)